# Dimension of a vector space and bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a vector space and $C$ be the matrix associated to a bilinear form $f$ on $\mathbb{V}$ with respect to some choice of initial basis. Show that if the dimension $n$ of $\mathbb{V}$ is odd then there is no basis of $\mathbb{V}$ such that the matrix of $f$ under this new basis is $-C$.

Let the initial basis be $\{ e_1,...,e_n \}$ and the new one $\{ x_1,...,x_n\}$. The entries of the $C$ matrix are $c_{ij}$ which by definition are $f(e_i,e_j)$. By hypothesis also $f(x_i,x_j) = -c_{ij}$. I understand that we must show that there is no transition matrix $A$ such that $-C = A^t C A$, where $A^t$ denotes as usual the transpose of $A$.

How does this matrix looks like given that $f(e_i,e_j)= -f(x_i,x_j)$? I guess that once we know this the exercise will be easy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a counterexample. Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$. Then $-C=C$ in $M_n(\Bbb F_2)$.

Comment: If $n=1$ let $x_1 = i e_1$. Then $f(x_1,x_1) = f(i e_1, i e_1) = -1 f(e_1, e_1) =- c_{11}$ as desired. What is wrong here !? @DietrichBurde

Comment: 2 more counter-examples:  **(i)** let $C= \mathbf 0$, then $C= -C$ and **(ii)** let this bilinear form be over $\mathbb C$ and be given by the dot product.  Set $C:= I$ and $A= i \cdot I$.  Conclude $-C = A^T C A$.   I'm sure there are many more counterexamples to this "exercise".  I would guess you were supposed to tell us that the field is $\mathbb R$ and that the form is non-degenerate-- solution: take the determinant.